# How to format date variable in c# to match stored date in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I'm reading in a date from a textbox into a C# program and comparing to a date to entries in a SQL database. I can't get them to match, despite a SQL query of the date showing there are entries for that date.

I've tried saving to a variable with `.Date` to try and strip off the `hh:mm:ss`, which had no results. I've attempted `DateTime.ParseExact` to change the format to match the database.

```
if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDate))
{
      CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      DateTime completeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "M/d/yyyy", culture);
      requests = requests.Where(x => x.CompletionDate == completeDate);
}
```

I expect to find a match for two records in the database when I search for `1/28/2019`. I'm getting no results. I've tried other entries and also not found any matches. No error messages are being generated.

Comment: Do you store also the Time part in the database column _CompletionDate_?

Comment: Yes, it does, it has 00:00:00.000 - is there a way to add that to my variable or strip it off the database entry when I compare the two?

Comment: Ok but is there a way to perform it within the Razor statement that is accessing the database?

Comment: To be sure to not miss anything due to time parts I would use _requests.Where(x => x.CompletionDate >= completeDate && x.CompletionDate < completeDate.AddDays(1));_

Comment: What is a sample `searchDate` string that you're passing through? What is the value of `completeDate` if you inspect it? What is the exact value in the database that you are expecting the LINQ query to find?

Comment: I got it to work by creating a second variable and using completeDateNext = completeDate.AddDays(1), then searching between those two dates.  Linq doesn't support AddDays directly.  But thanks much - it works now!

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework then you can use [EntityFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions?view=netframework-4.8) to [TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_EntityFunctions_TruncateTime_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__) and compare it with your date. This is not a good solution though as it will not work with indexes because it is translated into TSQL `convert` statements. Range search is better here.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply compare two `DateTime` objects, they will consider not only date but also time.

To compare just the date, you can use `DateTime.Date` property.

```
var date1 = new DateTime(2019, 7, 29, 15, 23, 44);
var date2 = new DateTime(2019, 7, 29);

Console.WriteLine(date1 == date2);
Console.WriteLine(date1.Date == date2.Date);
```

The first will return `false`, the second will return `true` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is time isn't a factor your comparison and shouldn't be included. You need to explicitly compare date parts only...

```
requests = requests.Where(x => x.CompletionDate.Date == completeDate.Date);
```

Answer (score -1):

```c
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

DateTime completeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "M/d/yyyy", culture);

completeDate = 1/28/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

if the date stored in db is `1/28/2019` it wont match.